# Localtunnel with Traefik and ssh

Tags: reverse-proxy, traefik, ssh-tunnel, tunnel, localtunnel

I'm looking for a solution with Traefik to do my own Ngrok alternative.
I have multiple a home assistant with the Autossh plugin installed on an another server and would like to access to it by entered the url : home-assistant.server.com

Authssh is configured with the remote forwarding port : 44400:localhost:8123, on ssh port (22).

I found this Traefik configuration (Traefik V1) but would like to use Traefik V2.
I obtain a Bad gateway with my new Traefik configuration.

Do you have any idea to resolve it ? Thanks.

Here, my Traefik V2 configuration :

**traefik.toml**

```
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"

[api]

[providers.docker]
  endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"

[providers.file]
  filename = "/etc/traefik/services.toml"

[certificatesResolvers.mycertificate.acme]
  email = "contact@server.com"
  storage = "acme.json"
  [certificatesResolvers.mycertificate.acme.httpChallenge]
    entryPoint = "http"
```

**services.toml**

```
[http]
  [http.services]
    [http.services.nas]
      [http.services.nas.loadBalancer]
        [[http.services.nas.loadBalancer.servers]]
          url = "http://localhost:44400"
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    restart: always
    image: traefik:chevrotin
    ports:
    - "443:443"
    - "80:80"
    volumes:
    - /srv/traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml
    - /srv/services.toml:/etc/traefik/services.toml
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    - /srv/acme.json:/acme.json
    labels:
    - traefik.http.routers.nas.entrypoints=https
    - traefik.http.routers.nas.rule=Host(`home-assistant.server.com`)
    - traefik.http.routers.nas.service=nas@file
    - traefik.http.routers.nas.tls=true
    - traefik.http.routers.nas.tls.certresolver=mycertificate
```

Comment: I think this question belongs on ServerFault - try there?

Comment: In your `services.toml`,  You are pointing to `localhost:44400`. This will be your own traefik container and I believe nothing is running on port 44400 of this container. I think you need to pass the correct hostname or ip of your local server.